# How to fix the problem with second layer condition in redux reducer?

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm making an application that gives tasks to learning methods. One of the reducers should change the state of the task mark: pass true or false depending on the solution of the task. But this code doesn't change the state of reducer.

My code:

```
const initialStateMethods = {
  array: methodsObject
};

const methods = (state = initialStateMethods, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_MARK":
      return {
        ...state,
        array: state.array.map(method => {
          if (method.id === action.methodIndex) {
            method.tasks.map(task => {
              if (task.id === action.taskIndex) {
                return { ...task, mark: action.mark };
              } else {
                return task;
              }
            });
          }
          return method;
        })
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

But the value of the method changes easily and it works. 
Example:

```
const methods = (state = initialStateMethods, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_MARK":
      return {
        ...state,
        array: state.array.map(method => {
          if (method.id === action.methodIndex) {
            return { ...method, name: "newName" };

          }
          return method;
        })
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

So I assume that the problem is in the multilayer structure

A small piece of the original object:

```
export const methodsObject = [
  {
    name: "from()",
    id: 0,
    tasks: [
      {
        taskName: "Task №1",
        id: 0,
        mark: null
      },
      {
        taskName: "Task №2",
        id: 1,
        mark: null
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a return statement next to the call of your map loop:

```
...
case "CHANGE_MARK":
  return {
    ...state,
    array: state.array.map(method => {
      if (method.id === action.methodIndex) {
        return method.tasks.map(task => {
          if (task.id === action.taskIndex) {
            return { ...task, mark: action.mark };
          } else {
            return task;
          }
        });
      }
      return method;
    })
  };
```